# How to create a crossword puzzle in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created 10 x 10 TextBoxes and the user should input the words into the relevant TextBoxes for the position of the words. And I save everything into a textfile like this:

[image]

Then on WPF side , I read the textfile and populate the TextBoxes in a panel but the problem is that the crossword puzzle has down and across hints that lead you to the answer and each hint will have a number to indicate which is which. However I can't think of a way to link the number's puzzle number to the hints down and across number. This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Notice the numbers (I edited them in paint to visualize what I want) beside the across and down, I need that numbers to be displayed.

In my database, I stored the location of the file in a table, and the hints and answer in another table like this:

[image]

And this is the hints (across and down) and answer:

[image]

I am using Entity framework lambda expressions to retrieve the across and down.

Appreciate any help on this to link the assign the numbers to Across and Down from the puzzle.

This is my code to display the puzzle :

```
  protected void Across()
    {
        IList<ModelSQL.puzzlecontent> lstAcross = daoPuzzleContent.GetAcross();

        foreach (ModelSQL.puzzlecontent lista in lstAcross)
        {
            Label tbA = new Label();
            tbA.Content = lista.Hint;
            tbA.Width = Double.NaN;
            tbA.BorderBrush = Brushes.CadetBlue;
            tbA.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
            stackPanel1.Width = Double.NaN;
            stackPanel1.Children.Add(tbA);
            words.Add(lista.Answer);

        }
    }

    protected void AddPuzzle()
    {
        // foldername of the txt file.
        //  using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText((@daoWordPuzzle.GetfileURL())))
        string[] fileData = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\apr13mpsip\Desktop\OneOrganizer\OneOrganizer\WordPuzzle\educational.txt");

        string[] lineValues;

        int row = 0;
        int col;
        int hint = 1;

        string[][] rowcol = new string[fileData.Length][];

        foreach (string line in fileData)
        {
            lineValues = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);


            rowcol[row] = new string[lineValues.Length];

            col = 0;

            foreach (string value in lineValues)
            {
                rowcol[row][col] = value;
                col++;
            }
            row++;

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < rowcol.GetLength(0) ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowcol[i].GetLength(0) ; j++)
            {


                int iadd =  i+1 < rowcol.GetLength(0) ? i+1 : 100;
                int iminus = i-1 >= 0 ? i-1 : 100;
                int jadd =  j+1 < rowcol.GetLength(0) ? j+1 : 100;
                int jminus = j-1 >= 0 ? j-1 : 100;
                var self = rowcol[i][j]; // current value

                var top = iminus == 100 ? "" : rowcol[iminus][j];
                var bottom = iadd == 100 ? "" : rowcol[iadd][j];
                var left = jminus == 100 ? "" : rowcol[i][jminus];
                var right = jadd == 100 ? "" : rowcol[i][jadd];

                //ACROSS HORIZONTAL
                if (
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left))
                  )
                {
                    wordAcross = "";
                    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                    {
                        wordAcross += rowcol[i][k];
                        if (k == 9)
                        {
                            puzzlewordAcross.Add(wordAcross);
                            // print hello and live
                        }
                    }

                }

                //DOWN VERTICAL
                if (
                     (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                     (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                     (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left))
                    )
                {

                    wordDown = "";
                    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                    {
                        wordDown += rowcol[k][j];
                        if (k == 9)
                        {
                            puzzlewordDown.Add(wordDown);
                            // print holy and leducated 
                        }


                    }
                }

                //Check Top , Left , Bottom , Right value.                      
                if (
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left)) ||
                    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(self) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(top) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(right) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(bottom) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(left))

                   )
                {

                    TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
                    tbox.Height = 50;
                    tbox.Width = 50;
                    tbox.Text = hint.ToString();
                    wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tbox);



                    tbox.GotFocus += (source, e) =>
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbox.Text))
                        {
                            string Str = tbox.Text.Trim();
                            double Num;
                            bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);
                            if (isNum)
                                tbox.Text = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tbox.Text = "";
                        }

                    };

                    hint++;
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox tbox2 = new TextBox();
                    tbox2.Height = 50;
                    tbox2.Width = 50;
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(self))
                    {
                        tbox2.Background = Brushes.Black;
                        tbox2.Focusable = false;
                    }
                    wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tbox2);
                }// end of top bottom left right.

            }


        }
    } // End of AddPuzzle()
```

Code to display Across and Down :

```
    protected void Down()
    {
        IList<ModelSQL.puzzlecontent> lstDown = daoPuzzleContent.GetDown();

        foreach (ModelSQL.puzzlecontent listd in lstDown)
        {
            Label tbD = new Label();
            tbD.Content = listd.Hint;
            tbD.Width = Double.NaN;
            tbD.BorderBrush = Brushes.CadetBlue;
            tbD.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
            stackPanel2.Width = Double.NaN;
            stackPanel2.Children.Add(tbD);


        }
    }

    protected void Across()
    {
        IList<ModelSQL.puzzlecontent> lstAcross = daoPuzzleContent.GetAcross();

        foreach (ModelSQL.puzzlecontent lista in lstAcross)
        {
            Label tbA = new Label();
            tbA.Content = lista.Hint;
            tbA.Width = Double.NaN;
            tbA.BorderBrush = Brushes.CadetBlue;
            tbA.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
            stackPanel1.Width = Double.NaN;
            stackPanel1.Children.Add(tbA);
            words.Add(lista.Answer);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - Is it linking the Down/Accross hints to a specific textbox? Is it writing the hint-number in the textbox? Also, are you storing the answers in both a textfile and in the database, or is the textfile only for the initial creation of the crossword?

Comment: textfile is only to save the position of the answer and i populate them back using textfile . u see those numbers in the textboxes  i have to link them with Across/Down hints , like 1.for God our Lord is then user will know DOWN number 1 will be the answer to that Down hints.

Comment: Alright, I just noticed that the answer is also stored Hints-table. Anyway, your question is how to relate the hints to a specific position/textbox? That needs to be stored together with the hints. I'm not sure what "PuzzleContentID" is - can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Surely you just want to add the hint for each number into a `ToolTip` on each `Control` that displays the numbers?

Comment: @LarsKristensen Yes thats my question ! as for puzzlecontenID its just a primary key ID , i haven't did anything about that .

Comment: @Sheridan No it needs to be related to the position in the puzzle

Comment: I was talking about the little numbers that you drew using Paint. When you add those numbers into controls (in the puzzle), put the clues into their `ToolTip`s.

Comment: I know what u mean but i duno how to do it such that they know which clues to put in which position . i am new to programming , pls bear with me if i can't understand what u mean and bad english.

Comment: Now I'm confused... do you want do you know how to add the little numbers (with clues in popup `ToolTip`s) into the TextBoxes?

Comment: Are the upvotes for "Ooh cool, a crossword", or for "Great question"? As I don't think this is a good question. Can you please edit your question rephrase what part you actually need help with?

Comment: @Sheridan No i meant is how do i find out which clues belongs to which number , u see from my picture of DB , because now , in my DB , clues have answers tied to them so how do i do it just that when in the Across/Down the clues will have the number tied as the position number of the puzzle , in my code i can print out the answers . Sorry for bad english

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry for my bad english , if u play before crossword puzzle , they have numbers in their clues and the numbers are positioned in the puzzle itself .. now i need to know how do iattach the numbers to my clues according to the puzzle number position .

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to make the numbers part of your text file input.  For example, the first line of your text file could be `[1]h,e,l,l,o,,,,,` , the second line could be `o,,,,,,,,,` , the third line could be `[2]l,i,v,[3]e,,,,,,` and so on.  When you parse this, you know that each square bracket pair signifies the start of an across clue and/or a down clue.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You may need to re-define your data model here because I think you have failed at the first hurdle - systems analysis. It catches us all out when we just want to write code and always means a big refactor.</strike>

Think about your domain here. Crossword puzzles. If we are a reading a newspaper puzzle and you dont know the answer to a clue, what do you say when you you ask a friend.

> 6 letters, clue is 'blah blah'

...followed by any letters that you already know.

Now we know that the puzzle needs to know how many letters in each answer and that each answer needs a clue. We also know that letters are hidden until you fill them out but we need to know the right answer at some point.

How does the puzzle present itself in the back of the paper? Clues are not written as 1,2,3 etc. They are 4 down, 1 across etc. Now we know that you need some position data stored.

You can achieve this is 2 ways.

**1. Have each clue as its own entry complete with text**

Clue '1'
Direction 'Across'
Position '1,1'
Answer 'Hello'
Description 'Greeting'

Work out the grid size from the entries and position letters accordingly.
Pros: Easy to work with. All the information in one place
Cons: Possible data corruption. This method can define 2 different letters in the same position.

**2. Seperate Entries but answer text in grid**

This is very similar to how you have it now but your seperate the text into a CSV grid as you demonstrate in the first screenshot. You then have entries for the clues as in method 1. but omit the 'Answer' field.

Your code will have to :

1. work out the grid size
2. populate a grid
3. populate the list of
   clues
4. convert the users entries to a CSV text file so that you
   can validate the input against the answers and
5. tell the user if

As for linking the clues to the entry text boxes. Set the `Tooltip` property of each `textbox` with descriptions of the clues that include the letter.
    they got it right.

Finally **(and this is probably the bit you want)**, add the correct number to the entry text box, you have to take advantage on WPF's layout pipeline. Dont just put a textbox in your grid, put another grid in! I'll show you how it should look in XAML, but you may want to generate it in code.

```
<Grid>
  <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_NumberLabel"/>
  <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_LetterEntry"/>
<Grid>
```

Use that instead of a plain textbox in any square where you want a number.

Comment: i appreciate your time and effort in replying . As i just started to learn programming a month back , i came only this far . , sorry for my bad english and poor understanding . My main question here is to attach the position numbers to the  the clues according to  the position of the textbox numbers , so everything i did was wrong in the beginning ? As for checking of answers , i was actually plan to add the correct ans first in a List<string> then i add the user input text into the list<string> and compare them to check for wrong/correct answers.

Comment: I understand your method 2 up til point number 3 , i dun have any idea about CSV and stuffs , thanks for providing me an alternative way , i will look into it if my current doesn't work well .

Comment: CSV means 'comma seperated values'. Its a format for tabular data and the one that you are already using.  Item 3 states that you will need to show a list of clues with the numbers next to them and your code needs to build that list using the data.

Comment: Additionally. There is no wrong answer if it works but understanding EXISTING solutions to problems (the newspaper crossword) can help you design your code. This involves abstraction and decomposition -key methods for object orientated design.

Comment: well thats interesting abt CSV , but there is no solutions to my current problem other than an alternative way to do it?

Comment: I'm just suggesting a way to approach a problem that might have avoided your trouble. Frankly, I'm concerned thatI don't evne know what your problem is. Was it displaying the small numbers in the grid using WPF?

Comment: My problem is to attach the position numbers in the puzzle to the Across/Down clues .

Comment: What do you mean by 'attach'? Are we talking about the display or referencing in code? If display, I answered it already.

Comment: I have already solved it , i gotta post the answer after i clean up the codes.